# gedit cannot open file in external drive - permission denied

Tags: permissions, gedit

Just installed 18.04 and gedit cannot open files inside the external drive.
I double-click in file and says "permission denied" (doing this in e.g. /usr/ .. works OK)
I do not want to use sudo in command line everytime.. 
Permissions look ok in file  -rwxrwxrwx
Seems an issue with external drive permissions (just gedit).
I am a newby, hope you can help! thanks.

Comment: how is the external drive mounted? that can cause issues depending on how its done. Is it connected through USB .. did you mount it with a command or did it "auto mount" when attached?

Comment: I did not did nothing. I connect through USB and it worked. So I would guess it "auto mounted" itself

Comment: not sure if its installed by default but you can try `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and either install it or check to see if it's the latest version... if not installed yet ... try again after it is installed and see if you can get write access to your external drive .. you may have to unplug and replug the drive in

Comment: if `ntfs-3g` is installed and you still don't have write access try `sudo apt-get install ntfs-config` then run it `sudo ntfs-config` and select "Enable write support for external devices" and see if that solves the problem :) .. that's the best I can come up with

Comment: ntfs-3g was installed and latest version. Then I installed ntfs-config, run it (with warning message Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module") and selected  "Enable write support for external devices" , but still doesn't work. But now when I want to unmount it says "authentication is required to unmount name-of-drive mounted by another user", which I do by using my password, does this means something? Or any other suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found solution! And simple... in UbuntuSoftware, search gedit, and you will find together with , launch, remove another button saying permissions. click it and select "on" for "write/read in external drives.. grrr

Comment: ahhhh..now computer booted to black screen "welcome to emergency mode". Now, only with external drive connected it passes through error message and the ubuntu works! I am betting on sudo ntfs-config did something. Help pleaaaase.
Now when I run sudo ntfs-config (with external drive connected), it persistently has the  tick enabled for wiritng in internal device (as well as the external drive tick in advanced configuration). And I need always to give password to unmount..

Comment: one solution I read in other posts would be to edit the fstab. One way is to comment the entry for the device which would be this one

UUID=3800C36C00C33024 /media/adovalente/3800C36C00C33024 ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0 

but would this work? Now, my only way to enter ubuntu is with external drive connected so I do not want to mess this up again. Or should I delete "nodev,nosuid," in another post seem that their line did not had this... will wait for some help before doing. Any help appreciated!